# Node JS dealing with error "Cannot Post /"

Tags: node.js

I am trying to send a post request and dealing with this error "Cannot POST /". What can be the problem? I am using a Postman to send a Post request to our server. My post request is

> localhost:4000

Here is my index.js code:

```js
const Joi = require('joi');
Joi.objectId = require('joi-objectid')(Joi);
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const users = require('./routes/users');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mongo-games')
    .then(() => console.log('Now connected to MongoDB!'))
    .catch(err => console.error('Something went wrong', err));

app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api/users', users);

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));
```

And here is my user.js code:

```js
const Joi = require('joi');
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); //needed for validation & creating user mongodb schema

const User = mongoose.model('User', new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 50
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 255,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 1024
    }
}));

function validateUser(user) {
    const schema = {
        name: Joi.string().min(5).max(50).required(),
        email: Joi.string().min(5).max(255).required().email(),
        password: Joi.string().min(5).max(255).required()
    };
    return Joi.validate(user, schema);
}

exports.User = User;
exports.validate = validateUser;
```

And my users.js code:

```js
const { User, validate } = require('../models/user');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    // First Validate The Request
    const { error } = validate(req.body);
    if (error) {
        return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
    }

    // Check if this user already exisits
    let user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (user) {
        return res.status(400).send('That user already exisits!');
    } else {
        // Insert the new user if they do not exist yet
        user = new User({
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password
        });
        await user.save();
        res.send(user);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

What am I missing here? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your middleware is- app.use('/api/users', users);
and your post is about that route.
In your postman> URL > you need to write localhost:4000/api/users.
because this is the URL that gets to the router.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are sending request to the `/api/users`. Looks like you are trying to send it to `/` which you are not handling.